# Pass a predefined date to dijit calendar

Tags: javascript, calendar, dojo

I got my dijit calendar up and going so I want to take a date and stick it in my calendar.
I get the date from

```
return "<a href=\"#\" onclick='return false'>" + dateClick + "</a>";
```

And my Calendar function is

```
cal_1 = new dijit.Calendar({
           value: new Date()
        });
```

And I would like to pass the dateClick into my cal_1 the dateClick is format like `2012-10-10 00:00:00`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

save dateClick as a Date() object and using Steven Leviathan's [dateFormat](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) library to extend the Date object you can format it as you wish.